# jQuery closest ID to my list

Tags: jquery, parent, closest

Hope you can advise, I'm trying to find the closest or a parent id. I think its maybe easier to show you.

Here is some example code.

```
<li id="search" class="widget color-green">
  <div class="widget-head"></div>
    <div class="edit-box" style="">
    <li class="item">
      <label>Available colors:</label>
        <ul class="colors">
          <li class="color-yellow"/>
          <li class="color-red"/>
       </ul>
    </li>
  </div>
</li>
```

So in this example If I click on list item color-red or color-yellow I want to find out the value of the closest id  which in this example would be search

Ive tried a number of ways and cant seem to pin it down.

Hope someone can advise and thank you in advanced if you can.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This will meet your requirements:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.colors > li').click(function() {
        alert($(this).closest('[id]').attr('id'));
    });
});
```

It checks for the nearest parent of the clicked element that has the `id` attribute.